# Step by Step explanation for using Rails secrets.yml without exposing keys to public repo when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, secret-key

I am using Rails 4.1.1 and ruby 2.0.0

I've currently ignored my secrets.yml file to my gitignore for github.

**secrets.yml**

```
development:
  secret_key_base: numb3r57ndl3tt3r5

test:
  secret_key_base: differentnumbersandletters13531515

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %>
```

If this production key is dynamic, where does it read it from? Where do we provide that info? How does that info get to heroku without getting to github?

I already have a secret key environment variable in my heroku app's settings.
I think it was created when I used the heroku_secrets gem https://github.com/alexpeattie/heroku_secrets to run the rake comment `rake heroku:secrets RAILS_ENV=production`

Can someone explain the conceptual steps, as well as the practical steps on how to utilize secrets.yml properly without exposing secret keys to the public?

If you can also go over with adding another secret key for a different API for instance, that would be much appreciated as well.

I'd like to understand what is happening in the steps in the explanation, rather than something like "do this, do this, do this". Also, if there is code, please specify which file it should be put in, instead of just giving the code, and assuming the reader will know where it goes just based on the code alone (**stern look at heroku guide writers**)

Thanks! =]

Comment: typo, should be <%= ENV %> instead of <%= EN %>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use this key `<%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %>`

On your local machine you can set environment vars in your shell, like (bash or zsh)

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE="yourkeybasehere"
```

And simulate that you run on production (but at your local machine) like

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

However, deploying on Heroku, you can use what they call config vars, by running `heroku config:set` command for your app.

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=yourkeybasehere
```

Then the Rails app will populate this config var into secret.yml

```
production:
  secret_key_base: yourkeybasehere
```

Hope this explains thing you need to understand.

Though, if you would like to play and test.
One option is trying to edit your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file and put the config var you want to display, for instance USERNAME config var

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= ENV['USERNAME'] %></title>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Then deploy to heroku and run

`heroku config:set USERNAME=gwho`

You should see 'gwho' at the page title.

More details about Heroku config vars: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

More details about Rails 4.1 secrets.yml: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config/secrets.yml

Comment: So I actually create and persist an environment variable on my computer. If close then open the bash, do I have to set the variable again for my machine? What if I shut down and turn on my computer?

Comment: This command `heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=yourkeybasehere` will set and apply the the config var on your app at Heroku. Therefore, the env var you set will persist on Heroku not on your local shell.

Comment: So I just have to upload my secrets.yml file to github as it originally was, with `<℅= ENV=['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] ℅>`. What does the export line do?

Comment: Ideally, secrets.yml should not be on github because it usually contains sensitive data (But that's your decision if it's confidential or not). But I would suggest you to use `heroku_secrets` gem you have mentioned instead of pushing secrets.yml to github. The export line is how you set shell session environment variable.

Comment: Shell session! Just what I needed to know =)

Comment: How do we chat in SO?

Comment: I'll just type here. The whole point of a key is to restrict access right? If I'm setting the env var on heroku, where am I setting a matching key on my end? What does not having the right key on your own machine block? Does it block uploading, or does it just not let heroku serve the webpage?

Comment: It's not used to restrict your access. This file is usually used to store external APIs keys such as Facebook, Twitter, Instagram etc. But if the name of the key is `secret_key_base`, it is only used for verifying cookies. You don't need to set any matching on your end.

Comment: Ooooooo thank you so much. You were able to tell me what Iccould not find on the googles for gosh almost 3 hours.

Comment: why do I need to hide the production environment key? What bad thing can happen if someone gets this key?

Comment: As I said in the earlier comment. Because of `secret_key_base` is used to verify signed cookies. That means anyone who has this key can use the key to read your production site's customers cookies information.

Comment: i'm very sorry i miseed what you said. Got a massive headache, but still trying to push on. Thank you for clarifying what signed cookies protection is. God you are soo good. Do share if you have a blog or a social media link

Comment: well crap. i understand how it all should work, but i can't get it to work =(

Comment: hah, well. I should probably turn this into blog post, If that is really useful. And what's not working is generally a question, you should explain thoroughly step by step and it's technically time to be in a new thread for the specific problem you're facing. Happy coding! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58269/discussion-between-gwho-and-zdk).

Comment: There's a bit of confusing info here. Your Rails app has to know that `secret_key_base` is in `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` if that's where you're going to store secret_key_base. If that reference is in `secrets.yml`, then you **must** check `secrets.yml` into your repository. Even if the Heroku config var is set, if Rails doesn't know where to look, it won't run. However, there are more places you can refer to `secret_key_base`. For example, there is nothing wrong with setting `config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` in the configure block in `application.rb`, and it will work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (hopefully simple) step by step guide FOR HEROKU that should be performed prior to pushing files (secrets.yml) to GitHub, or another host.

*I am not an expert on this topic but this worked well for me and seems like a good solution.  It combines info from answers to this question as well as answers to this question ([How do you keep secrets.yml secret in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689674/how-do-you-keep-secrets-yml-secret-in-rails/43197901#43197901)) to provide a simple guide :)

1) Copy secrets.yml to another file named secrets_backup.yml

you should now have two files with the same content as secrets.yml

2) Add `secrets_backup.yml` to your .gitignore

3) Change the text in `secrets.yml` to the following

```
development:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE_DEV"] %>
test:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE_TEST"] %>
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

4) `cd` to your rails project folder on the command line

5) In the terminal type `heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE_TEST=<pasted key>`,
where `<pasted key>` should be copied and pasted from the `test: secret_key_base:<key>` which is in `secrets_backup.yml`

6) In the terminal type `heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE_DEV=<pasted key>`,
where `<pasted key>` should be copied and pasted from the `development: secret_key_base:<key>` which is in `secrets_backup.yml`

7) My `secrets.yml` file already had the SECRET_KEY_BASE instead of the actual key, so I suspect yours will too.  But if not, set the SECRET_KEY_BASE variable as the other two were set above.

8) Push your repo to GitHub and Heroku

9) Smile because you're the G.O.A.T and show off your sweet website!